# Wrap XML tags on long list of items?

Tags: android, html, xml

I have a long list of languages and I need to wrap them with XML tags. 
My list looks like this:

```
Afrikaans   
Albanian    
Arabic  
Azerbaijani 
Basque  
Bengali
```

...

 
 
and so on. I need to wrap the with `<item>` tags like this:

```
<item>Afrikaans</item>  
<item>Albanian</item>   
<item>Arabic</item>
```

Is there any tool online or in Android Studio? I couldn't find any.

Comment: You need to do that at runtime inside an app ? If not, you could write a small program to do just that, or use Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to modify the file manually, you can use regular expression and find and replace way. The regular expression is `^(\w+)$` and the replace string `<item>\1</item>`. This works in Notepad++

You need slightly different replace string in Android studio. It should be '$1'

The search expression I provided works if the string is each line does not have spaces at the end. If you have spaces in strings, you can use the expression '^(\w+)(\s*)$'

Comment: I am Notepad++ newbie. How to use regex and replace there?

Comment: You solution worked only for "Hebrew". I have no idea why :D. Maybe there's something wrong with the regex.

Comment: Yes, that is possibly because of the trailing spaces. See my updated answer.

Comment: Worked. Thanks very much!